# Get last value of a specific column from all sheet Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook. with lots of sheets (at least 100+ sheets).

all sheet has same design and format. every sheet has **L column**, where I calculated the results. and at the end of the **L column** I subtotal the L column values.

I got all sheet names with the below vba code.
[Home Sheet (Summary Sheet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF7CC.jpg)

```
Sub GetAllSheetNames()

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = i
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet
         .Rows(1).Insert
         .Cells(1, 1) = "INDEX"
         .Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
         .Cells(1, 2) = "SHEET NAME"
         .Cells(1, 2).Font.Bold = True
         .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

where my **summary sheet** has **column A** with **index header** and **column B** has **sheet name** header.
and in the **column C**, I need subtotals of all **L columns last values** from all sheets.

I tried code mentioned above.

[Data Sheet-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXWsw.jpg)

[Data Sheet-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCAWE.jpg)

> Got Error After Running the code given in answer.

[Compile Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtenE.jpg)

Comment: You might consider working with [`ListObject.TotalsRowRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.totalsrowrange), since it appears that those sheets have tables (`ListObject)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it.

```
Sub GetAllSheetNames()
    Dim iR As Long, sht As Worksheet
    With Sheets("Rent Summary")
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("a1:c1").Value = Array("INDEX", "SHEET NAME", "SUBTOTAL")
        .Range("a1:c1").Font.Bold = True
        iR = 2
        For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            If sht.Name <> .Name Then
                .Cells(iR, 1) = iR - 1
                .Cells(iR, 2) = sht.Name
                .Cells(iR, 3) = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Value
                iR = iR + 1
            End If
        Next
        .Columns("A:C").AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It gives **compile error, Sub or Function not defined.** and highlights **End With**

Comment: I can complie VBA project without any error. I guess you might miss the last code line.

Comment: Is there any problem with Table format?
Because all other Sheets has same table format.

Comment: I don't think so. I would suggest you to load a screen shot (your code and complie error pop-up window) on your post.

Comment: Thanks Mr @taller_ExcelHome. It's my mistake.

Actually, I copy the code in mobile browser, paste it in WhatsApp, then open WhatsApp in laptop browser, copy code from WhatsApp and paste it in my modules. that's why error accrued.
Now I directly copy paste from browser to module and everything is fine.